# How to make dynamic page based app at runtime Apple Watch

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I want to build a page based app with an unknown number of pages until runtime.

Is there is a way to check how many pages are needed by making an api call and then make that many pages. I want to do this initially when the app loads without doing a reload in the awakeWithContext which causes the loading activity icon to appear twice?

Answer (score 2):

You have to first set identifier for your Interface controller in a storyboard under the Attributes Inspector and then add this identifier in  a mutable array for the number of times as your pages count.e.g. Suppose you have an array of Data Objects named 'objects' as a result of an API Call.So call the 'presentControllerWithNames:contexts:' method of WKInterface Controller to modally present the Page-based Navigation of your Views.

```
            NSMutableArray *controllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (NSInteger i=0; i<[objects count]; ++i) {
                [controllers addObject:@"yourInterfaceControllerIdentifier"];
            }





    [self presentControllerWithNames:controllers contexts: objects];
```

Comment: If you do the 'presentControllerWithNames' then it puts another layer onto the watch. The watch will load the root interfaceController then will present these modally on top of the root interfaceController. I want to avoid that second layer. If i do a reloadRootControllersWithNames then I can achieve the pages on the same root layer but I get the loading icon twice which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `WKInterfaceController`'s class method `+reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:`

What I did was create a root interface controller and, on the `-init` method of it, load the pages I needed, like so:

```
- (void)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [WKInterfaceController reloadRootControllersWithNames:@[@"Controller1", @"Controller2"]
                                                     contexts:nil];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The controller's names are the identifiers you defined on the storyboard.